# insert data in table throuth one form C# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

![home base library collection database][1]

http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/1159/finallibrary.jpg

i am developing a small book database application for my home base library. i can insert 
record in multiple related table in sql server 2008 from this command 
 i not know that how can i insert it from visual studio 2008 C# or vb,net 
i want to create a form for book information and i want to insert book record from one form to database 
it is possible ?  please provide me any tutorial for it 
thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @bookid INT
DECLARE @authoridId INT
DECLARE @classid INT
DECLARE @catagaryid INT
DECLARE @publisherid INT
DECLARE @paddressid INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT  INTO dbo.author
        ( aname )
VALUES  ( 'visnu priya singh'  -- author_name - varchar(50)
          ) 
SET @authoridId = @@IDENTITY

INSERT  INTO dbo.class
        ( classname )
VALUES  ( '12'  -- classname - nvarchar(255)
          ) 
SET @classid = @@IDENTITY  
INSERT  INTO dbo.catagary_main
        ( catagaryname )
VALUES  ( 'networking'  -- catagaryname - nvarchar(255)
          )
SET @catagaryid = @@IDENTITY    
INSERT  INTO dbo.catagary_sub
        ( subcatagaryname ,
          catagaryid 
        )
VALUES  ( 'computer networking' , -- subcatagaryname - nvarchar(255)
          @catagaryid  -- catagaryid - int

        )          
INSERT  INTO dbo.publisher
        ( pname ,
          pconnumer 
        )
VALUES  ( 'asian computek book' , -- pname - nvarchar(255)
          '011232' -- pconnumer - nvarchar(255)               
        )
SET @publisherid = @@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO dbo.paadress
        ( p_house_no ,
          parea ,
          pstate ,
          ppin_code 
        )
VALUES  ( '7/001,first floor,'   , -- p_house_no - nvarchar(255)
          'ans road, ganj' , -- parea - nvarchar(255)
          'delhi' , -- pstate - nvarchar(255)
          '110002'  -- ppin_code - nvarchar(255)
        )
        SET  @paddressid=@@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO dbo.Publisher_aadresss
        ( publisherid, paddressid )
VALUES  ( @publisherid, -- publisherid - int
          @paddressid  -- paddressid - int
          )         
INSERT INTO dbo.books
        ( book_name ,
          authorid ,
          yop ,
          edition ,
          price ,
          isbn_number ,
          classid ,
          catagaryid ,
          publisherid ,
          Pages
        )
VALUES  ( 'computer networking course' , -- book_name - nvarchar(255)
          @authoridId , -- authorid - int
          2006 , -- yop - int
          'first edition' , -- edition - nvarchar(255)
          187.50 , -- price - int
          '81-7317-9-7' , -- isbn_number - nvarchar(255)
          @classid , -- classid - int
          @catagaryid , -- catagaryid - int
          @publisherid , -- publisherid - int
          368  -- Pages - int
        ) 
        SET @bookid=@@IDENTITY 
        INSERT  INTO dbo.book_written_by_author
        ( bookid, authorid )
VALUES  ( @bookid, -- bookid - int
          @authoridId  -- authorid - int
          )


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible............ you can use [ADO.NET](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet).

Refer:

[Adding a row to an SQL server DB using Visual c#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/e0fef04a-4815-4d8a-be1d-a636f5447619/)

[How to insert Data to Ms SQL server 2008 using C#.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/340852/How-to-insert-Data-to-Ms-SQL-server-2008-using-Csh)

Comment: any tutorial on net this is my schema http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/1159/finallibrary.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Save it as a stored procedure and just call it from your code behind

Comment: any tutorial on net this is my schema img715.imageshack.us/img715/1159/finallibrary.jpg